# Можно ли продлить срок конкурсного вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение, конкурс

Господа, стало интересно. Срок конкурса на вопрос неделя (кто не знает, это семь дней)))))... Если на вопрос нет ответа или он не удовлетворяет, например не полон. Можно продлить срок конкурса или надо дождаться окончания и объявить конкурс заново?

Comment: Аналогично, за 7 дней ответа нету.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конкурс объявляется максимум на неделю. Если за неделю вы не выдали награду, у вас есть ещё 24 часа, чтобы это сделать. Потом конкурс завершится автоматически.

Продлить срок конкурса нельзя.

Если первый конкурс не принёс результатов, то маловероятно, что второй принесёт. Вместо конкурса попробуйте задать новый вопрос, более конкретный и точный.